# How to simplify an exponential functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, complex

I have many defined functions as below and trying to simplify it with MATLAB `simplify()` function

$g(t) = 14.9je^{j31°} e^{j2t} - 14.9je^{-j31°} e^{-j2t}$

How can we simplify these kind of functions using MATLAB?

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic.

Comment: You don't need MATAB to simplify this. Pencil, paper and casual acquaintance with a math book will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbolic math is included in MATLAB, but rarely used in signal processing. There are cases, nevertheless, when we wish to use symbolic math packages to simplify some expressions. One such alternative is also Wolfram-Alpha web application.

Anyway, apart from a misunderstanding, you indeed have a (simple) mathematical problem:

Given a complex number $z$ , you have
$$ z + z^* = 2 ~\mathcal{Re}\{ z \} $$
or a complex-valued function $f(t)$
$$ f(t) + f^*(t) = 2 ~\mathcal{Re}\{ f(t) \} $$

If you look at your function $g(t)$, you will see that it's a sum of a complex-valued function $f(t)$ and its conjugate $f^*(t)$, where

$$f(t) = 14.9 ~j~e^{j 31^o} ~ e^{j 2t} $$
and its conjugate
$$f^*(t) = - 14.9 ~j~e^{-j 31^o} ~ e^{-j 2t} $$

hence

$$g(t) = f(t)+f^*(t) = 2 \mathcal{Re}\{ f(t) \} $$

Then you can see that

$$\mathcal{Re}\{ f(t) \} = \mathcal{Re}\{ 14.9 ~j~e^{j 31^o} ~ e^{j 2t} \} =\mathcal{Re}\{ 14.9 ~e^{j (121^o +2t)} \} = 14.9 \cos(121^o +2t)$$

Then your $g(t)$ is:

$$ g(t) = 2 \times \mathcal{Re}\{f(t)\} = 2 \times 14.9 \cos(121^o +2t) $$